# jQuery: how to "declick" a open slideToggle div?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Is it possible to "declick" an active div that has been opened with slideToggle?

This function opens multiple text divs independently from each other, but the open div's `click(function()` is still clickable, and so the div will bounce closed and then open again. It's mostly a user experience; I'd like users to be unable to click an already opened div.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/auUxk/12/

```
$(".entry-content").hide();
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
    $(".entry-content").hide();
$(this).parent().children(".entry-content").slideToggle(500); });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="entry-post">

    <h2 class="entry-title">Post Title 1</h2>

       <div class="entry-content">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum

    </div></div>

<div class="entry-post">

       <h2 class="entry-title">Post Title 2</h2>

       <div class="entry-content">Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum 

    </div></div>
```

Comment: did you mean to have two closing div tags?

Comment: @xixonia, if you look at the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auUxk/12/) he posted, it's not a mistake, but presumably an artefact of copy-pasting the code excerpts.

Comment: Arg. My mistake. HTML corrected. That's the markup generated by the Wordpress loop.

Comment: Fixed my answer to do what you're asking. sorry I missed the point the first time around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  It seems most people didn't notice that you want to keep only one open div at a time.

http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/WnpGv/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".entry-title").click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var $content = $this.next(".entry-content");
        if (! $content.is(":visible")) {
            $(".entry-content:visible").slideToggle(100);
            $content.slideToggle(500);
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
This UI pattern is called an `accordion`.  There are also [lots of plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-accordion-menus-tutorials/) which achieve this in more dramatic/complicated ways.

Also, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has an accordion [in their API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Accordion).  Keep in mind that the accordion API [is being revamped for 1.9](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/02/jquery-ui-1-9-milestone-4-accordion-redesign/).

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Exactly what I wanted to do, in keeping with some other functionality on the site I'm building. I realize there are plugins and other complex accordions, but I want to keep it fairly simple. I will use the background color change CSS, too, in order to highlight the active text div. Is it possible to also give the h2 title a hover and active color?

Comment: @songdogtech - sure, a little bit of class toggling and a little extra CSS will handle that: http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/WnpGv/23/

Answer (score 1):

> "I'd like users to be unable to click
>   an already opened div."

**This will work: http://jsfiddle.net/xixionia/9P6My/**

```
<div>
    <h2 class="entry-title">Post Title 1</h2>
    <div class="entry-content">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>

<div>
    <h2 class="entry-title">Post Title 1</h2>
    <div class="entry-content">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .next('.entry-content:not(:visible)')
        .slideToggle(500);
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.entry-content
{
    display: none;
}
```

Or, you can always skip the css and use hide() on all of your entry-content classed elements. :)

This will toggle slide the first following element with the ".entry-content" class that are not visible, and will not slide them closed.

**If you would like to actually unbind yourself from the click event entirely, you could use undbind('click')**

```
$(".entry-title").bind('click', function() {
    $(this)
        .unbind('click', arguments.callee)
        .next('.entry-content')
        .slideToggle(500);
});
```

This would be the most savvy approach, and will *not* unbind your other functions which may be bound to the click event.

Or, you could unbind using event namespaces:

```
$(".entry-title").bind('click.slideopen', function() { // bind a click event with the slideopen namespace
    $(this)
        .unbind('.slideopen') // unbind all events in the slideopen namespace
        .next('.entry-content')
        .slideToggle(500);
});
```

You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/xixionia/9P6My/6/

Comment: I guess this will allow more than one "div" opened. That's what the "hide" is doing

Comment: Sorry, I meant the second hide. Originally he is hiding on each click. I've added the missing CSS.

Comment: My mistake; the HTML is corrected. That's the markup generated by the Wordpress loop.

Comment: If people are going to down vote my answer, please explain why.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'd like to be able to have only one div open at a time, like I have now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on close, you can do this:

```
$(".entry-content").hide();
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
    $(".entry-content").hide();
    $(this).parent().children(".entry-content:visible").slideToggle(500); 
});
```

This will close all divs, but not open it again. If you want to keep it open:

```
$(".entry-content").hide();
$(".entry-title").click(function() {
    var d = $(this).next();
    if (!d.is(":visible")) {
        $(".entry-content").hide();
        d.slideToggle(500); 
    }
});
```